# C++ inheritance, assignment

Tags: c++, inheritance, assign

```
class Base{ ... } a, b;
class Derived{ ... } c, d;

a = c;  // why does this work?
d = b;  // and why doesn't this work?
d = static_cast<Derived>(b)  // does this actually work?
```

And what happens exactly when assigning a base class to a derived class and reversed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For class types, assignment is done by calling a function, `operator=()`. If you don't declare that yourself, then a *copy-assignment* operator will be implicitly declared for you; for your classes, these look like:

```
Base::operator=(Base const &);
Derived::operator=(Derived const &);
```

So we can assign to a `Base` object from any `Base`, including derived types. That's why the first line works. Assigning (or initialising) from a derived class is sometimes called *slicing*: only the base subobject will be copied, and the derived class will be ignored.

We can't assign to a `Derived` from a `Base`, since its implicit operator requires a `Derived`. That's why the second line doesn't work, unless you were to declare an operator taking a `Base` argument.

The third line attempts to create a temporary `Derived` object initialised from `b`, then assign that to `d`. This will work if and only if `Derived` has a *conversion constructor* taking an argument of type `Base`.

Answer (score 2):

The public inheritance (which I assume you have implemented) relation in C++ is a 'is-a'-relation, so `Derived` is a `Base` which might be more specialized.

```
a = c;  // why does this work?
```

So it seems reasonable why you can assign `c` to `a`, as `c` is a `Derived`, but also a `Base` by definition.

```
d = b;  // and why doesn't this work?
```

On the other hand you can not assign the `Base` `b` to the `Derived` `d` as `d` might have members, that can not be initialized by a `Base`'s constructor.

Comment: thx for accepting my answer, but i think that Mike Seymour's answer shed's more light to the topic, so you might want to change you opinion?

Comment: hard choice... his answer's more comprehensive, but yours is quiet easier to understand (considering the 'is-a'-relation thing)

Comment: Personally I value this site for it's huge amount of quality answers. So I think the 'best' answer should be accepted, to be visible at the top. But everybody is free to examine the rest of the answers which are most likely an addition to the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Derived` is derived from `Base`, `Derived` **is** a `Base`, just with additional functionality. So a `Base` variable can be assigned a `Derived` variable, however, it will lose the extra functionality introduced in the `Derived` methods.

Reverse that logic, `Derived` is not a `Base`, it's more than that, so you can't assign the other way around, since that would add functionality, instead of removing what was gained.

As for the last line, I'm not sure if it would compile, but at best if it did, you would have undefined behavior for the reasons stated above.

Note that some of what I just said is false when getting into virtual inheiritnace, but you don't need to worry about that for now.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign an instance of a derived class to an instance of the base class all the base class members are assigned. `a = c;`

When you try to assigned an instance of the base class to an instance of the dervived class it would only assigned some of the members the members of the derived class would be uninitialized. `d = b;` Therefore this is not possible.